# How do I output a sentence to a Pages file from cpp

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream OutputFile;

    OutputFile.open("response_to_anything.Pages");

    OutputFile<< "hello"<<endl;

    OutputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, when I tried to open the new page file on my desktop(response_to_anything.Pages) the system shows that it's invalid.

Comment: Do you mean Apple's Pages document format?

Comment: How do you try to open the file created by the program? I mean using which app because this can be problematic.

Comment: ofstream represents a text stream file.. i.e. plain text. Also the way you try to open it, it's openeid in whatever working (curent) directory is, not necessary on desktop.

Comment: Hi, rawrex and Arslan. I output my informations onto the apple's pages document.

Comment: It's reads just fine(reads words from the page document), but if I tried to edit the document(output "hello"), it doesn't work.

Comment: by the way, thank you for answering my question.

Comment: There is no reading document here..you opened file as text stream (not sure what Pages file is like inside, but it's a proprietary format. for some file formats you may find libraries to work with them but it doesn't seem to be the case with Apple Pages. When you output that string, it's quite possible that you're corrupting an existing file if file isn't plain text.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to output that string to a plain text?